# Two-word adjective to describe a university life that has just started?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

For objects you can say things like *a brand-new car*. For beliefs you can write *a new-born Christian*. What about periods in life like university life?

Example:

> Emma has every reason to be happy. She had a trauma-free childhood, has an eccentric but caring mother, and is
>   starting a [...] university life, .

Comment: "and is starting a beginner's life at university"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["brand new"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brand_new) also works here. The phrase isn't only reserved for new physical objects that actually have brands.

From Wiktionary:

> Adjective
>
> utterly new, as new as possible

Answer (score 2):

And is starting a *grad student* or *undergrad* life.

Or

You could even just say *university life*; it is an adjective in itself.

Answer (score 1):

"[...]and she's a freshman in college" might just be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Emma has every reason to be happy. She had a trauma-free childhood, has an eccentric but caring mother, and is starting a **frosh** life.*

> **FROSH**
>
> *North American  informal*: college freshman:
>
> [as modifier]: ‘frosh week’
>
> Origin
>
> Early 20th century: alteration of freshman, perhaps influenced by
>   German Frosch 'frog' (in dialect use 'grammar-school student').

Comment: Worth noting that this does have a kind of fratty connotation. At least to me. Every time I hear someone use that word it immediately makes me reflexively dislike them at least a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Except for the fixed phrase “starting a brand-new [whatever],” I think the verb “starting” in your example would kind of render redundant any answer (other than “brand-new) that attempts to incorporate the notion of “newness” in the period of life, so maybe you should consider to either stick with “brand-new”(Parthian Shot’s answer) or else change “starting” to another verb in your example (which is what Ricky’s answer does).

People don’t “start” “brand-new cars” (except in the ‘turn the key’ sense), they ‘drive’ them; and we usually talk of “being/becoming”, not “starting [as]” a “re-born Christian” (although “starting **over** [as]” one would work).

All that to say that I think you need to find a neutral verb, one that doesn’t already include the notion of “newness,” in order to better flush out and analyze the two/hyphenated-word adjective that you seek, and I’d propose either “experiencing,” “tasting,”  or “living” (in addition to Ricky’s contracted use of “is”[without ‘starting’] in “she **’s**”) to use with “**[first-time](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/first-time?s=t)**”:

(with “experiencing”): “… and is experiencing [her/the] “first-time” taste [of university/adult/married life]”

(with “living/tasting”): “… and is living/tasting [her/the] “first-time” experiences [of university/adult/married life]”

> First-time: adjective 
>   1.  used, appearing, contending, etc., for the first time:  a first-time candidate.

(from Dictionary[dot]com)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a two-word *adjective*, but there are several two-word *nouns* one might use:

> She started a **new chapter** of her life upon entering the university.
>
> She got a **fresh start** when she began university life.
>
> University life was a **new beginning** for her.